# Aluminium + copper wire

Tags: wiring, aluminum-wiring

Can I twist copper on legacy aluminium wire using regular wire nuts or do I need to procure aluminium wire? The wires coming into my switch box are too short and I would need to extend them.

[image]

Comment: Ugh.  Not really sure what you should do -- installing Alumiconns or any other AlxCu lug is going to be a pain, and the COPALUM crimps require a specially trained/equipped electrician to install

Comment: Is putting in another box to house the splices not an option?

Comment: Did you put in a new load center and cut off the wires outside the old box? Why are the wires too short in the new box?

Comment: Never splice aluminum to copper with ordinary splices. Only use Alumiconns which are specifically made for this purpose.  The purple wirenuts are legal, but don't work.   Also consider an AFCI circuit breaker on the circuit, to avoid the worst problems with aluminum wire on copper terminations.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel -- no -- it would involve breaking a plaster wall. I need to install new switches in a box that is close to 100 years old and has aluminum armored cable coming in.

Comment: I pigtailed my aluminum wiring 35 years ago with good quality wire nuts and a now poorly regarded antioxidant, NoAlOx, and I have had no failures. Nevertheless I am now replacing these splices with AlumiConns. I use a torque screwdriver which I understand the UL rating requires. I must point out that AlumiConns are prone to a theoretical failure in which the installer fails to insert the wire all the way to the end of the port. 
Probably each wire should be marked ~20 mm (or whatever is appropriate) from the end to show that it has been inserted fully before tightening the screw.

Comment: Never splice aluminum to aluminum with ordinary wire nuts and ordinary techniques. I have found  that good quality wire nuts filled with good quality antioxidant (Burndy Penetrox) makes a good quality connection for Al-to-Al and Al-to-Cu. I abrade the stripped end of the aluminum conductor with emery cloth in the presence of anti-oxidant before twisting on the wire nut. I do not pre-twist the wires because this can make the joint too large for the wire nut I want to use. However, my good results with this technique is anecdotal because I have not conducted controlled testing.

Comment: See this   http://inspectapedia.com/aluminum/Aluminum_Wire_Repairs_Not_Recommended.php

Comment: @amphibient -- I've never heard of Al conductor AC/BX -- only bad old NM and newer AA-8k MC stuff.  Are you *sure* what you have is aluminum, not tinned copper?

Comment: I just posted a picture. I am pretty sure it's aluminum

Comment: Try cutting a short piece off the tip of one of the wires that *is* plenty long enough and seeing what the freshly cut end looks like: aluminum will be silvery all the way through, while tinned copper will look like well, copper on the inside.  Also, which is the way-too-short wire in your picture?

Comment: @amphibient -- another factor weighing against this being aluminum is that  your wires have old-style braided-cotton insulation on them -- AFAIK, all Al building wire in branch-circuit gauges was made using thermoplastic insulation...

Answer (score 2):

### Jumbo Pigtails are the answer here

Ordinarily, I'd recommend using AlumiConn lugs torqued to spec for a copper to aluminum pigtail job like yours; however, since your wires are already too short as-is, installing any sort of lug is going to be a pain in the arse.

So, your best bet is to install another (a single gang old work box should suffice, but run the box fill numbers to be sure) box "upcable" from where the culprit cable comes into the box, pull the old cable out of the old box, install it into the new box, strip back the jacket a bit, and terminate the ends of the old cables into AlumiConns.  You can then use some regular copper NM as a "jumbo pigtail" from the box with the AlumiConns in it to the existing switch box.  Put a blank cover on the new box, and you're set.

Comment: The 2-port AlumiConns would be what you would use to make this sort of splice to *both* make a good connection *and* to satisfy the code for up to 10 AWG wire. Absolutely do NOT use the UL certified Ideal purple wire nuts--they are expensive, they are prone to failure, and they occupy a large volume.  If you don't care about the code and want something that will make a good connection, and is cheap, then *I think* you can use a good quality wire nut (of the right size) like the 3M Scotchlok or the new 3M version, *and* use a good quality antioxidant like Burndy Pentrox, *used properly*.

Comment: @JimStewart -- actually, if you can't get AlumiConns, what you want to do is use a Al9Cu rated lug (even though the smallest AlxCu lugs around are 14-4 range, which makes them *far* chunkier than an AlumiConn)

Comment: The aluminum conductors of 30 A, 40 A, and 50 A circuits will not fit in an AlumiConn connector. For connecting these to copper wire you will have to use wire nuts (grey or blue *with antioxidant compound such as Penetrox* which may not be approved by code) or the larger set screw splice connectors which are approved by code for aluminum and I think come preloaded with antioxidant.

Comment: @JimStewart yeah -- the set screw connectors are what I'm talking about when I say "AlxCu lug" -- there's an off chance I'll be running some brand new aluminum in the future depending on what the inspectors turn up...

Comment: If you are running brand new aluminum, will this be for branch circuits to wall receptacles and will this be 10 AWG or even 12 AWG? If so, what receptacles and switches are approved for this?

Comment: @JimStewart -- this'll be in wireway to serve as a "trunk" for lots of branch circuits due to panel relocation -- I'll be dropping 8AWG for the 15A circuits and probably 4AWG for the 20A due to derate rules unless I split it into multiple wireways at 15 circuits to the wireway...

Comment: Getting back to the question of Al to Cu splices with 12 and 10 AWG aluminum, the WAGO spring lever connectors *with the WAGO antioxidant* might be OK.  Also note that the problem is not Al and Cu being dissimilar metals--the problem is the Al itself. Al to Al splices require the same treatment as Al to Cu splices.

Comment: I cannot install a new box.  The box is a constant

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you install a new "box", by which I assume you mean load center or electric panel. I was wondering how the wires came to be too short. Did you cut them off in the panel or outside the panel? Did the original installer not leave enough wire in the panel? My 1970 tract house with aluminum wiring was incompetently wired with not enough conductor in the wall boxes, but plenty in the panel.

Comment: [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6XkhjIw37g)  is what i got when i googled "jumbo pigtails"

Comment: Before using wire nuts with antioxidant see  http://inspectapedia.com/aluminum/Aluminum_Wire_Hazard_Reduce_2011.pdf